# override default int 8h,9h

Tags: c, assembly, int, interrupt

I'm trying to override the default interrupts so that if user presses and holds key, it will input only 3 times for every 5 seconds. If user presses and releases without holding, it will act as default

That's what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>

void interrupt (*Int9Save) (void);
void interrupt(*Int8Save) (void);
void start_press_limit(void);
void end_press_limit(void);
volatile int count=0,sum=0;

void interrupt h9(void)
{

    if(count < 3) {
        asm{
            PUSHF
            CALL DWORD PTR Int9Save
        }
        count++;
    }
}

void interrupt h8(void)
{
    asm{
        PUSHF
        CALL DWORD PTR Int8Save
    }
    sum++; /*counter*/
    if (sum >= 90) {
        sum = 0;
        count = 0;
    }
}

//main
int main(void)
{

    int scan_code = 0;
    char ascii_code;

    start_press_limit();

    do {
        asm{
            PUSH AX
            MOV AH, 0
            INT 16h
            MOV BYTE PTR scan_code, AH
            MOV ascii_code, AL
            POP AX
        } // asm
        printf("%c", ascii_code);

    } while (scan_code != 1);
    end_press_limit();
    return 0;
}

 void start_press_limit(void) {
     Int9Save = getvect(9); // save old func
     setvect(9, h9);    // new func
     Int8Save = getvect(8); // save old func
     setvect(8, h8);    // new func
 }

 void end_press_limit(void) {
     setvect(9, Int9Save);  // old func
     setvect(8, Int8Save);  // old func
 }
```

Comment: What behavior are you seeing?  Also, it seems very risky to access global variables from within your interrupt handler.  Personally, I've never tried to create an ISR within C code.. I'd greatly prefer doing this from assembly exclusively.

Comment: "This is what I have." Do you have a question to go with it, or is this meant as an announcement?

Comment: Please do not delete the content of your question. The answer(s) are useless without it.

Answer (score 0):

Intel manual clearly states that you cannot override the system default 0 to 31 interrupt vectors and one cannot predict the output if you override one of them.

Comment: No, the Intel manual doesn't say you can't change the interrupt vectors, nor does the CPU provide any sort of default value for the interrupt vectors. While it does reserve the first 32 vectors for it's own purposes, and defines a purpose for most of them, the fact is you can use at least some of them for your own purposes in a well defined manner. That's because **all PCs use reserved interrupts for other things**, at least up until the point a modern OS boots and redirect hardware interrupts. For example interrupt 8 is used for both for double exceptions faults and timer interrupts.